# Code after await statement doesn't run

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I know there're many similar questions in the forum, but I didn't find one as same as mine. Please look at my code below.

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Test();

        }

        async Task<string> Test()
        {
            var v = await TaskCaller();
            return v;
        }

        Task<string> TestTask()
        {
            new Task<string>(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                return "TestTask";
            });
            return null;
        }

        Task<string> TaskCaller()
        {
            var task = new Task<string>(() =>
            {
                return TestTask().Result;
            });

            return task;
        }
    }
```

The return v statement will never be reached. I need the result of TaskCaller to do more process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not starting any of your tasks so they cannot possibly complete (they'll be forever stuck with `Status = TaskStatus.Created`). Because those tasks cannot complete, your `await` will be awaiting indefinitely. Use `Task.Run`, which returns *hot* (started) tasks, in order to schedule work on the thread pool, i.e.:

```
Task<string> TestTask()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "TestTask";
    });
}
```

Or a better alternative:

```
async Task<string> TestTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return "TestTask";
}
```

Note that your `TaskCaller` actually returns a null `Task`. This is obviously a bug.

*Also: don't block on tasks via `Task.Wait()` or `Task.Result`*

Comment: Shlenskly What will `ConfigureAwait(false)` do ?

Comment: @Eldho, it makes the portion of the code immediately following the `await` execute on a thread pool thread. Without it your continuation (everything following `await`) *may* execute on the same thread which started the `Task` - good for UI applications, bad for non-UI-bound code.

Comment: The general rule is: if you need to touch the UI after your first `await`, *do not* use `ConfigureAwait(false)` - simply `await` your `Task`. If you don't need to touch the UI, use it.

Answer (score -1):

I made some changes in your code

```
 async Task<string> Test()
        {
            try
            {
                var v = await TaskCaller();
                return v;
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                throw ee;
            }
        }

        async Task<string> TestTask()
        {
            string ty = string.Empty;
            Task<Task> task = new Task<Task>(async () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                ty = "TestTask";
            });

            task.Start();
            task.Result.Wait();
            return ty;
        }

        async Task<string> TaskCaller()
        {
            string ty = string.Empty;
            Task<Task> task = new Task<Task>(async () =>
            {
                ty = await TestTask();
            });
            task.Start();
            task.Result.Wait();
            return ty;
        }
```